# Express route bundling

Tags: node.js, express

My routes.js file

```
module.exports = function(app) {
 //donesn't need to be authorized
 app.use('/login', require('./controllers/session'))

 //will need to be protected
 app.use('/user', auth, require('./controllers/users'))
 app.use('/vineyards', auth, require('./controllers/vineyard'))
 app.use('/varietals', require('./controllers/varietals'))
 app.use('/wines', auth, require('./controllers/wine'))
 app.use('/spectrums', auth, require('./controllers/spectrum'))
 app.use('/lockers', auth, require('./controllers/locker'))
 app.use('/logout', auth, require('./controllers/session')) 
}
```

The 'auth' middleware works when I make a get, or jsonp request, but if I use post it errors out, with a statusCode of 0, and content 'XMLHttpRequestProgressEvent XMLHttpRequestProgressEvent'. However if I go in the actual controllers and put the auth middleware on the actual post like below, it works.

```
router.post('/', auth, function(req, res) {});
```

Why is that? Is there a better way to make the middleware run before all calls to a controller then putting it on each individual route?

Comment: It should work, unless your routers/controllers use other middleware on which `auth` depends?

Comment: Just a note: you have varietals in the protected section, but don't call the auth middleware.